# ng-click not calling my controller function

Tags: angularjs

I've read lot of question with same text but none helped me, so I ask a new one.

I have a ng-app, ng-controller.

```
<div ng-app='mainApp'>
<div ng-init='period=".$_REQUEST['period']."' ng-controller='debtController'>
```

Then, some lines bellow, define them.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);                               
        app.controller('debtController', function(){
            openDebt = function(period){
                console.log(period);
            }
    });
</script>
```

And last but not least, a ng-click that calls the function defined.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openDebt('{{period}}')" />+</a>
```

So, if I click the '+' with the ng-click, nothing happens. But if I check the HTML there, and copy the text inside the ng-click, and then paste it in the console, it works. Why the function is not being called?

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: see the code i have for the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach

Notice the `as`syntax. This create an alias for the controller

```
<div ng-init='period=".$_REQUEST['period']."' ng-controller='debtController as debt'>
```

change the ng-click asociated to controller alias

```
<a href="#" ng-click="debt.openDebt('period')" />+</a>
```

In the controller code using `this` for associate the controller with the html

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);                               
        app.controller('debtController', function(){
            this.openDebt = function(period){
                console.log(period);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the variable without an expression

Change From:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openDebt('{{period}}')" />+</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openDebt(period)" />+</a>
```

Comment: didn't know that, thanks. Althought that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: what is the issue now?

Comment: The same, the function is not called but the function works... And if I copy th ng-click text in console it works.

Comment: you need to inject scope or create an alias, see how i am injecting scope before using scope. function($scope)

Answer (score 0):

Okay first embed the openDebt to scope inside the controller: `$scope.openDebt`. Second while in ng-click, you don't need `handlebar` to pass the value.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);                               
        app.controller('debtController', function($scope){
           $scope.openDebt = function(period){
                console.log(period);
            }
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openDebt(period)" />+</a>
```

**PLUNKER EXAMPLE:** http://plnkr.co/edit/OyhBWkrREtt2JT2IWuVN?p=preview

Comment: app.controller('debtController', function($scope){

Comment: see there function($scope)

Comment: If $scope is giving you error, perhaps you are minifying it, and breaks it, look how to inject correctly for minified js in angularjs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Did that but console sends error with injector problem and stops angular from working

Comment: Will check that, but the problem is solved with Gonzalo's answers. Thanks!

Comment: i will create a plnkr for you. wait.

Comment: see the plunker. i said you using alias can also solve the problem :) Neway cheers that it is solved.